Spring Boot Actuator - Health Endpoint - Spring Boot 1.5.0.RELEASE
I am trying to implement a spring boot actuator in legacy application. Already get all endpoints working using spring docs documentaion.
But when i execute the health endpoints its returning duplicate info. Anyone already has this problem.
My application.properties
management.context-path=/management
management.security.enabled=false
endpoints.health.sensitive=false
endpoints.metrics.enabled=true
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true
endpoints.hypermedia.enabled=true

I am already permiting all endpoints in spring security
The endpoint its returning this.
`{
    "status": "UP"
}
{
    "status": "UP"
}`

I am expecting the return just this
`{
    "status": "UP"
}`

